# How to add an hard disk to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-partitioning, hadoop2

I installed Hadoop 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and now I am trying to add an internal sata HD to the existing cluster.

I have mounted the new hd in /mnt/hadoop and assigned its ownership to the hadoop user

Then I tried to add it to the configuration file as follow:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>2</value>
   </property>

   <property>
       <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
       <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode, file:///mnt/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
   </property>

   <property>
       <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
       <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode, file:///mnt/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Afterwards, I started the hdfs:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-hadoop-Datastore.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hadoop-Datastore.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-hadoop-Datastore.out
```

It seems that it does not fire up the second hd

This is my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.default.name</name>
       <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

In addition I tried to refresh the namenode and I get a connection problem:

```
Refreshing namenode [localhost:9000]
refreshNodes: Call From hadoop-Datastore/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
Error: refresh of namenodes failed, see error messages above.
```

In addition, I can't connect to the Hadoop web interface.
It seems that I have two related problems:

```
 1) A connection problem
 2) I cannot connect to the new installed hd
```

Are these problem related?
How can I fix these issues?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I can ping the localhost and I can access localhost:50090/status.jsp

However, I cannot access 50030 and 50070

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode, file:///mnt/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
```

This is documented as:

> Determines where on the local filesystem the DFS name node should store the name table(fsimage). If this is a comma-delimited list of directories then the name table is replicated in all of the directories, for redundancy.

Are you sure you need this? Do you want your fsimage to be copied in both locations, for redundancy? And if yes, did you actually copy the fsimage on the new HDD before starting the namenode? See [Adding a new namenode data directory to an existing cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295848/adding-a-new-namenode-data-directory-to-an-existing-cluster).

The new data directory (`dfs.data.dir`) is OK, the datanode should pick it up and start using it for placing blocks.

Also, as a general troubleshooting advice, look into the namenode and datanode logs for more clues.

Comment: My understanding of namenode is that it manage the system tree directories and it knows the blocks where given files are located. Starting from this assumption I have placed inside the configuration file the folder of the data in the main disk and in the one mounted in /mnt/hadoop. However, now I get what you meant. I do not want to replicate the namenode in the added HDD.

Comment: I manually formatted the datanode and modified the namenode directory which now points only to the first HDD. Now the web interface starts but the datanodes still do not start

Comment: The log contains the following error:org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode’: Operation not permitted

Comment: It seems a permission problem but I gave permission to the hadoop user as follow: sudo chown -R hadoop.hadoop /usr/local/hadoop and the same error always appears

Comment: stupid mistake the folder was sudo chown -R hadoop.hadoop /usr/local/hadoop_store. Thank you very much indeed

Comment: How to add to hadoop windows's disk? I'm running hadoop windows

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment: "sudo chown -R hadoop.hadoop /usr/local/hadoop_store."
The owner has to be hdfs user. Try: 
sudo chown -R hdfs.hadoop /usr/local/hadoop_store.